# Original Sheet music especially for rock and pop music genres

Tags: discussion

Is it ok to ask for how to find original soundtracks of rock or pop music? For example, Lou Reed Perfect Day. This is fairly easy for classical music, in other music there is still scores but they are different, not only in terms of tonality but sheer notes.

Answer (score 0):

No - this is off topic here. It is not about practice or performance.

In general, google (or other search engines) will be your best bet for searching for anything online.